# why do my JPA object changes get written even though an exception is thrown?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a Java EE web applications, looks like this:

```
UserService.java -> UserDAO.java -> Oracle db
```

Object User.java is a JPA object.

In UserService, imagine I have a method something like this:

```
public User updateLastName(Long userId, String lastName) throws Exception {
    User u = this.getUser(userId);
    u.setLastName(lastName);
    if (lastName.equals("Jones")) {
       throw new Exception("No Jones allowed!");
    }
    this.updateUser(u);
}
```

The problem I'm having is, the exception gets thrown, but the last name "Jones" is still being written to the database.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put a break point on this.updateUser(u); and debug.  See if the method is actually getting called.

Comment: @kmb385 Thanks, the line is not getting hit, and the exception is getting thrown.

Comment: Is it se or ee project? Are you sure that the data is committed? Maybe you see uncommitted changes?

Comment: @RobertHume Something else must be committing the data